# Torque of a force

Tags: calculus, physics, vector-analysis, vectors, cross-product

The torque $M$ of a force $\overrightarrow{F}$ as for the point $O$ is defined as the product of the magnitude of the force $\overrightarrow{F}$ and the perpendicular distance of the point $O$ and the action line of $\overrightarrow{F}$.

The torque vector $\overrightarrow{M}$ is the vector of magnitude $M$ of which the direction is perpendicular to the plane of $O$ and $\overrightarrow{F}$, the orientation is determined by the right-hand rule.

Show that $\overrightarrow{M}=\overrightarrow{R} \times\overrightarrow{F}$, where $\overrightarrow{R}$ is a random vector with start point the $O$ and end point on the action line of $\overrightarrow{F}$.

[image]

Could you give me some hints how we could show this??

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Find the magnitude of the cross product and think about what rule you use to find the direction of the cross product of two vectors.

Comment: Is the magnitude equal to $$||\overrightarrow{R}|| ||\overrightarrow{F}|| |\sin{\theta}|$$ ?? The cross product is perpendicular to the two vectors. Do we have to use the right-hand rule??